# How to assign the icon name shown in pinned start tile menu of Windows 10 with Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, tile, startmenu

I know the default icon name pinned in start menu is that of exe file. But the pinned icon name of bds.exe which is Rad Studio exe file shows 'RAD Studio 10.2' in start menu.

How can I set the name like the above? I tried to change all names of Version Info but nothing happens.

Comment: What does the Windows documentation say?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan uwp documents and examples are found but not so helpful unlike windows 32 apis.

Comment: You didn't say it was a UWP app

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is not a uwp app. so uwp documents and exmaples are not helpful i said.

Comment: Right. So read the docs for Win32 then.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i guess it is not implemented by win32 apis.

Comment: Well, RAD Studio is a Win32 app isn't it. So that rather disproves that idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can pin a program to start menu or start screen (Windows 8 and newer).

One is by pinning the application executable which results in pinned icon to have the same name as the executable has.

Another more commonly used approach is by pinning the shortcut to your program's executable instead. By doing this the pinned icon actually has the same name as the shortcut to your executable does.

Do note that this shortcut does not need to be in start menu but can be anywhere, even in application folder.

So don't pin the executable but instead the shortcut to it. And as you know shortcut gives you the ability to chose whatever name you desire, regardless of the executable name.

EDIT:

After looking at this some more I found another information about the location of shortcuts to pinned items which might be helpful to you

https://superuser.com/questions/171096/where-is-the-list-of-pinned-start-menu-and-taskbar-items-stored-in-windows-7

Comment: i know how to use a shortcut to handle a tile. but bds.exe is pinned with that name without a shorcut.

Comment: i didn't know the shortcut 'RAD Studio 10.2' was in the folder already. probably it was made during installation automatically. after removing it, bds.exe shows 'bds' not 'RAD Studio 10.2'. not the case of uwp, tile display name seems to be displayed only by a shorcut. thanks.

Comment: Also do note that this shorcut does not need to be in start menu but it can be anywhere. So some programs have custom shortcuts in their application folder which can then be pinned to the start menu or start screen.

Comment: wpf can modify a tile name too. during publishing it not just building, a shortcut which has predefined name is made automatically.

Comment: I have added another source of information to my answer which might come in handy